# What is the most effective way to buy bitcoin from swiss francs?

Tags: exchanges, currencies

The most effective way I could find so far was Mt.Gox. The costs that are involved are still quite prohibitive. But this then boils down to the question: [what is the most effective way to get your money out of [Insert your Exchage here]-exchange.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/639/whats-the-best-way-for-someone-in-israel-to-move-money-in-and-out-of-mt-gox-an)

Is there *any* better way to convert your currency? (Swiss Francs in my case)

Comment: Voted to close as too localized.

Comment: @ripper234: How is that too localized? Swiss francs are a major currency (and even if not, this question would be of interest to a not insignificant user group for *any* currency).

Comment: @Thilo - because we have lots of similar questions, and it's not feasible to answer them all in a consistent manner. Also the answers will change with time, etc... don't won't to argue over it here though, it's just close vote, nothing major.

Answer (score 3):

Switzerland takes part in the SEPA (Single Euro Payment Area); the Bitcoin exchanges that do SEPA transfers will probably be the ones with lowest costs for you.

I expect your bank will charge you for converting between CHF and EUR. If you want to convert often you may want to open a euro denominated account instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [BitStamp](http://bitstamp.net/) which lists CHF as a currency it will convert for trading (international wire).

See also the [wiki page on selling bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins).