# transfer money to mtgox with visa or mastercoard

Tags: mtgox, payment

I am looking into add funds tab from mtgox and I can not find an option with visa or mastercard.

```
E-Currencies:
Liberty Reserve (Instant funding - NO FEE)
PerfectMoney (INSTANT funding - 1% FEE)
Pecunix (INSTANT funding - NO FEE)
HD-Money (INSTANT funding - NO FEE)
VouchX Vouchers (INSTANT funding - NO FEE)
CosmicPay (INSTANT funding - NO FEE)
C-Gold (INSTANT funding - 5% FEE)
SolidTrustPay (WITHIN 1 to 2 business days - 8% FEE)


Banking and other payment methods:
SEPA Euro transfers (WITHIN 1 business day - NO FEE)
International Wire Transfer in USD (WITHIN 1 to 2 business days - NO FEE)
Wire Transfer in GBP (WITHIN 1 to 2 business days - NO FEE)
CASH deposit at 10,000 locations in the USA (WITHIN 1 hour - at 3.75% fee!)
INSTANT EURO BANK TRANSFERS (Coming soon!)
LOCAL AUSTRALIAN BANK DEPOSITS (Coming soon!)
```

Is it possible? If no, what is the easiest way to do this using MasterCard

Comment: See [How can I buy Bitcoin via a Credit Card or Paypal?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/how-can-i-buy-bitcoin-via-a-credit-card-or-paypal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can't easily buy hard money (like Bitcoins) with soft money (like credit card payments). The problem is that customers could reverse or dispute the soft money payment and the trader couldn't get the hard money back. To cover their costs should this happen, they'd have to give lousy exchange rates.

These lousy exchange rates would chase away legitimate customers. But scammers wouldn't mind, they're not going to pay anything anyway. So the scam rate goes up, the fraud losses go up, the legitimate customers get chased away, and so on.

There do exist businesses doing this, but expect extensive credit checks, waiting periods, demands for detailed documents, and so on. Also, expect to pay too much.