# How to buy bitcoins with amex debit card?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I have a debit card and would like to buy bit coins, is there a way with amex?

Comment: See [this question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/how-can-i-buy-bitcoin-via-a-credit-card-or-paypal).  The short answer is: probably not, a Bitcoin seller who accepted credit or debit cards would be extremely vulnerable to fraud.

Comment: Most probably you won't be able to do so, for the same reasons most crypto-currency dealers avoid being paid via Paypal or other, non Am.Ex. credit cards (fear of charge-backs). Don't know if AmEx allows you to withdraw cash from your credit card, that would be accepted by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase has options for both debit and credit.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on this to clarify the credit card option works with Coinbase.  I logged into my Coinbase account and it does have an option to add a credit card, but it says it charges credit cards only as a backup, similar to the way PayPal works.