# Are there any services hosting Bitcoin-related ads for websites?

Tags: websites

Say one owns a Bitcoin-specific website and they want to get some ad revenue for Bitcoin-related ads. Are there any websites that host such ads and provide the necessary code for displaying and monetizing them, just like AdSense would, or does one have to contact individual Bitcoin websites and strike deals with them?

Comment: aren't Google Ads [reverted it's ban](https://www.finextra.com/blogposting/17922/a-year-on-from-googles-upturned-ban-on-crypto-ads) on crypto-ads? did you try it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not anything like adsense yet, but there are smaller ad platform. Here are a few:

1. http://dailybitcoins.org/ they offer both ads by number of impression and per click.
2. http://www.bitcoinadvertisers.com/ they claim to be the biggest, I do not know how true that is.
3. http://anonymousads.com/ They have a significant presence in the Bitcoin community.
4. http://puppytwist.com/ they are pretty simple to get started with, high payout too

Answer (score 4):

http://www.operationfabulous.com/

I think kiba and noagendamaerket were working in it. It is an ad service so you can promote yourself with Bitcoins or get Bitcoins if you have a site with traffic.

Comment: As a general rule, when answering with just a link, please also provide some more info about the site that you're linking to. It will make the answer a lot more helpful and hopefully earn you a couple of upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a newly launched network which users view and answer question  that you set up. Which could let users know more about the features of your site. The pricing is down to 0.0001 per valid view (the user answered a correct question). Also offering detailed reports such as users location. users answers etc.

the site is: http://bitcoin.chromaticcreative.net

Comment: Somewhat related: *[How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91)*.

Answer (score 3):

I have a bit of news, there now is something like adsense. BitcoinAdSmart is a intelligent Keyword/GeoIP driven ad service for bitcoin.

Check out [BitcoinAdSmart](http://www.bitcoinadsmart.com)

> BitcoinAdSmart offers the most fully intuitive bitcoin advertising
>   service available. We work with Bitcoin publishers as well as regular
>   publishers. We accept payment in Bitcoins, Paypal and all major
>   credit/debit cards. We also offer various payout method to publishers,
>   namely bitcoin and paypal. To deliver qualified advertisement(s) for a
>   given request, the BitcoinAdSmart engine applies a proprietary Yield
>   Optimization Algorithm to determine the appropriate rank and cost for
>   each advertisement. Our algorithm considers factors such as relevancy,
>   targeting match, keyword match type, qualified filter criteria,
>   historical earnings, current bid amount, and more to determine what
>   advertisement is qualified to be shown, where (rank), and what it
>   should be billed. Take advantage of our targeted ads and relevant
>   traffic, become a publisher or an advertiser today!
>
> The result: Increased revenue for publishers along with increased
>   performance for advertisers.
>
> Your typical ad server delivers advertisements based on pre-selected
>   filters such as Geographical Targeting, Content Channel Matching,
>   Keyword Matching, and/or Date Scheduling.  While these filters are
>   needed and considered a norm, advertisers want, and need, more
>   targeting control. BitcoinAdSmart is the first bitcoin advertiser to
>   offer intelligent keyword drive ad serving.
>
> In today's demanding on-line marketing efforts, advertising relevance
>   has become one of the most important factors for both the advertiser
>   and the publisher.  Advertisers can experience increased traffic from
>   interested, motivated, and highly targeted, visitors, while publishers
>   can enjoy an increase in advertising revenue thanks to the higher
>   click-through rate.
>
> What differentiates BitcoinAdSmart from the simple keyword targeting
>   methods typically found in other advertising products available today
>   is our proprietary contextual targeting engine.  With BitcoinAdSmart,
>   publishers no longer have to manually specify relevant keywords for
>   each page that include ads. Instead, our proprietary contextual
>   targeting engine finds relevant keywords from the page content,
>   matches those keywords to the available ads, and then delivers
>   matching ads.  Combining our proprietary contextual targeting engine
>   with content channels, geographical targeting, and scheduling, bitcoin
>   advertisers  and other advertisiers can enjoy an increased volume of
>   conversions.

They outline their indexing process here:

[Contextual Indexing Process](http://bitcoinadsmart.com/contextual-indexing-process.html)

Comment: Links have died

Answer (score 2):

[CoinURL](http://coinurl.com)

We offer interstitial ads like AdFly and text/image keyword-based contextual advertising similar to the Google AdSense. Targeting by location, language and devices. Network-wide and particular website bidding. Strong protection against fraudulent clicks. Zero commission and deposit/withdrawal limits. Easy revenue sharing between website owners and content creators.

Answer (score 2):

The site that comes closest to Adsense today in the Bitcoin realm seems to be http://www.CoinURL.com.

It's relatively new but to my experience has been the most convenient to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[anonymousads.com](http://anonymousads.com) offers ads that aren't pay-per-click or pay-per-impression; they're a fixed monthly fee determined, essentially, by auction. They accept bitcoin.

and

[operationfabulous.com](https://www.operationfabulous.com) is pretty much the same.

Comment: As a general rule, when answering with just a link, please also provide some more info about the sites that you're linking to. It will make the answer a lot more helpful and hopefully earn you a couple of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Some more:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Advertising
- http://www.throughads.com
- http://bitcoinadvertisers.com
- http://thebtcnetwork.com

Comment: all your URLs are non-functioning