# How can I buy Bitcoins with Australian Dollars?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

Please! I just want to get them! How hard does it have to be? I've spent some 5 hours today trying to figure it out. I am in Australia.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 7):

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/659) answers the more general question "How do you obtain Bitcoins?"  Most commonly, people use a Bitcoin exchange to exchange local currency for Bitcoins.

Here is a [list of exchanges](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/list/) split by currency and whether they're currently active or not.

Comment: At this time, MtGox's fee starts at 0.6% and decreases with your trade volume over the past month.

Comment: Highest rated answer needs to be rewritten/replaced, as World Bitcoin Exchange is no longer active. In addition a number of new australian bitcoin exchanges have emerged. This page still ranks very highly in google, and it would be good to see it updated with a more complete answer. Any takers?

Comment: Don't use MtGox!  It has big problems with withdrawals of USD and Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

LocalBitcoins.com has buy and sell online in AUD and also AUD cash trade:

https://localbitcoins.com/country/AU

If you buy from a trader with good reputation history and fast response times you can get bitcoins within an hour.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia there are currently a number of options for buying Bitcoins. Below is a list of exchanges that I am aware of that accept AUD.

**Fixed Price Exchanges:** (Create order at fixed price and transfer funds after order is created. Usually same day service)

- [Bit Innovate](https://bitinnovate.com) Accepts over the counter bank deposits (our site)
- [Spend Bitcoins](https://www.spendbitcoins.com/buy/) Accepts over the counter bank deposits
- [bitXoin](http://www.bitXoin.com/) Accepts over the counter bank deposits

Another good resource is https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins which usually contains up to date information on all the ways to buy bitcoins in all countries.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.spendbitcoins.com/buy/ - You can deposit at any NAB, Commonwealth Bank, Westpac or ANZ bank across australia

Comment: This is identical to another answer from March 7th (by someone with the last name as you). :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [WeExchange](https://www.weexchange.co/main.php) accepts AUD.

However I personally wouldn't recommend it, since for me it has shown some worrying login problems.

Answer (score 0):

bitcointrader is becoming a favored Australian exchange for cash over the counter deposits offering competitive rates and good service

https://bitcointrader.com.au

Answer (score 0):

I have to send a big shout out for the crew at my two favorite exchanges bitXoin [https://www.bitXoin.com/] and spendbitcoins [www.spendbitcoins.com.au] as they are both local to me (Gold Coast) and fast, safe and professional to deal with.

In particular, if you want to buy bitcoins over the counter and you are in the Gold Coast area then visit the bitXoin offices there at Chevron Renaissance Centre in Surfers Paradise.

Prices are very low (basically lower than Mt. Gox prices) and processing happened within an hour or two depending on what time I get the deposit into the bank (mornings seem slightly faster).

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with any bitcoin companies and my opinion is based on over 10 seperate transactions since start of 2013. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These people are Australian-based, and accept AUD.  They also have a merchant service.  I haven't tried them yet, maybe when the price goes down again...

http://coinjar.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://purchasebitcoin.com.au they are Australian owned and they deliver in less than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of BTC/AUD exchanges:

http://exchangewar.info/coinprice?btc_aud

Answer (score -1):

You can also [Buy Bitcoins](https://btcmarkets.net/signupIndividual) at BTC Markets an Australian [Bitcoin Exchange](https://btcmarkets.net).