# Easiest way to buy Bitcoin from Montreal/Canada

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Apart bank wire is there a fastest/cheapest way to buy Bitcoin? I checked the map with the live seller but there is none in Montreal.

Thank's.

Comment: Marginally more specific than [How can I get bitcoins in Canada?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/how-can-i-get-bitcoins-in-canada)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the original poster of this thread. It looks like the option are plentiful since then. Here is my updated list:

- http://cavirtex.com
- https://harbor.ly/
- https://www.canadianbitcoins.com
- http://cadbitcoin.com
- https://www.bitcoinscanada.ca
- http://www.nanaimogold.com
- https://quickbt.com
- https://btcquick.com
- Peer-to-peer: https://localbitcoins.com

Last update: 6 January 2015

Comment: If you feel that your answer is now the best, you may accept it in order to help others that find this question.

Answer (score 7):

Deposit cash at a bank is a deposit method for CAVirtex.   TD or CIBC banks.  You don't need to have an account to deposit.

- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/VirtEx

Update:

CaVirtEx no longer allows cash deposits at any bank. You now make a Bill Payment to an established Payee, and CaVirtEx credits your account about 2-3 days later.

- https://www.cavirtex.com/news

There is a new service called harborly which allows you to buy and sell bitcoins in Canada directly with your bank account.

- [https://harbor.ly](https://harbor.ly/)

Comment: I can vouch for CAVirtex as one of their customers - however the cash deposit is now only available via RBC

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply go to your bank and send money to MtGox via Bank Transfer. MtGox provides you with their Swift code and bank account information, and it's straightforward and easy. Follow MtGox instructions they provide. I've done it multiple times with RBC - you can even do it online, I've done that too, it's called an International Remittance at RBC. (Online transfers are limited to $2500 a day).