# How can I get bitcoins in Canada?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, canada

I want to exchange my Canadian dollars for Bitcoins. How can this be done? If it helps I have some American cash.

Comment: Vancouver now has an ATM http://www.straight.com/life/742621/vancouvers-newest-bitcoin-atm-pulls-pacific-central-station

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are a few options available to Canadians:

- [Local Bitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/)
- [BitBuy](https://bitbuy.ca/)
- [CoinSquare](https://coinsquare.io)
- [QuickCoin](https://quickcoin.ca)

There are also a few exchanges that [accept CAD deposits larger than $100](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/currency/CAD.html):

Comment: CaVirtEx isn't closed (anymore!)

Comment: Harborly is closing down. They recommend Coinbase (which isn't listed here either) and Quadriga.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how many you want, the fee/convenience structure changes. I'd break it up into three sizes.

---

Large (over $500, multi-day delivery):

https://CaVirtEx.com - **Canadian Virtual Exchange** (Biggest Canadian-based exchange)

https://CanadianBitcoins.com - **Canadian Bitcoins** (smaller Canadian exchange, not self-serve)

https://harbor.ly - **Harborly** (Buy bitcoins directly with your bank account)

---

Medium ($100 - $500, within hours):

https://LocalBitcoins.com - **Local Bitcoins** (classified ads for cash sales in your city)

http://Kijiji.ca - **Kijiji** (more cash deal listings)

http://Meetup.com - **Meetup.com** (Find local enthusiast meetups, lots of buy/sell)

http://mycelium.com/ - **Mycelium Local Trader** (Android App for finding Bitcoin sellers)

---

Small (Under $200, within minutes):

https://QuickBT.com - **QuickBT** (Instant, using Interac Debit, higher fee)

---

Now Closed:

https://www.LibertyBit.com/news - **LibertyBit**

https://MtGox.com - **Mt Gox**

https://btcQuick.com - **btcQuick**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [harborly](https://harbor.ly/). They let you buy bitcoin and litecoin directly with your Canadian bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Instant exchange service I'm using myself and recommending to everyone else cause they don't store the coins and fiat, had recently expanded to Canada.

Check this out I believe this is exactly what you need: http://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/247exchangecom-covers-canada-with-instant-ways-of-buying-bitcoin-570478861.html