# How do I put bitcoins in my "Wallet"?

Tags: wallet

I want to Buy something using bitcoins but I am not sure how to put bitcoins in my "Wallet".

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Is your question really "how can I get some Bitcoins"? Or is it about the standard client's wallets? Or does "wallet" include online wallets? Do you already have the Bitcoins? If so, in what form? If not, how do you plan to pay for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins). @Kanfood3223, try to clarify what you mean, otherwise this question will probably be closed.

Comment: I am also interested in this topic. How do I add bitcoins to a (e.g Copay.io) Wallet

Comment: I Found an answer to my own question. This bitcoin market seems to work https://localbitcoins.com/

Answer (score 5):

When new Bitcoins are issued (7,200 per day, on average) they go to those who are mining for bitcoins.  At one point in time, mining to acquire bitcoins was something that was relatively easy to do.  That is no longer the case.  So now to acquire bitcoins one would normally buy bitcoins at an exchange.

What options are available to you will differ based on where you are, what payment methods you have available, how quickly you need the bitcoins and how many you intend to buy.

For instance, in the U.S., the fastest method to buy bitcoins is to use the service BitInstant where you deposit cash at a bank and they send the funds to an exchange.   The cheapest method is to do a bank transfer using Dwolla as intermediary -- however that is not very fast.  Other methods are shown here:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

Then once you have purchased the bitcoins at the exchange, you would simply withdraw them and send them to a bitcoin address from your own wallet.  Using the Bitcoin.org client you would click the Receive bitcoins button and generate a new address.  That is the address you would copy and then from the exchange paste that address when asked from their withdrawal page.