# Where can I buy bitcoins from Ireland without photo ID?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

My available methods of payment would be laser(Ireland debit card scheme), mastercard, visa or a bank transfer. 
I'm a beginner user in Ireland.
I'd also prefer not to have to verify my account with a photo ID. 
I won't be spending large sums of money either so the cheaper the better, and the money will be spent pretty much instantly so i'm not too worried about having THE most secure option if it means i'd have to pay more.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Intersango's](https://intersango.com/) service lately, and am happy with it. You can deposit by SEPA bank transfer, no ID required.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not wanting to get verified by ID, the [Mt.Gox option](https://mtgox.com/) is not possible.

This page would provide you some information:
http://www.btcwallet.org/contact/fill-up-your-wallet-buy-bitcoins-option-one/
This 1. option is trading which is quite dangerous, you´d better read this before:

1. http://wiki.bitcoin-otc.com/wiki/OTC_Rating_System
2. http://wiki.bitcoin-otc.com/wiki/Using_bitcoin-otc%23Safety:_avoiding_fraud

And the similiar way but I think the easier one would be [bitcoinary](https://www.bitcoinary.com/)

But firstly you should check if there is someone near you at [localbitcoins](http://localbitcoins.com)

You might also consider using up your EUR account and then using SEPA to deposit to [bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/), which is probably best europe exchange with good support.

Comment: LocalBitcoins.com and local cash trade guarantees maximum anomity. Do not use online payment if you want to remain anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

[Eircoin.net](http://eircoin.net) is one option I used before. The response was prompt and the whole transaction (despite a mistake on my part) went almost instantaneous.

[Localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/) is another possibility if you want to trade in cash within your neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

https://quickbitcoin.co.uk/ are based in the UK, and accept bank transfers from any bank within the faster payments network - that includes many Irish banks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Aurumxchange.com](http://www.aurumxchange.com)

for SEPA transfers. Buy their VouchX with and then redeem them on any of the exchanges suppporting them, e.g. you can redeem them without fees at [Vircurex.com](https://vircurex.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [irishbitcoins](http://irishbitcoins.com/) and they where very fast, I have only used the deposit method once but I wasn't asked for ID. The guy even met me in Dublin the next week and i got more from him, sound lad. sure send them an email and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can find friends of friends that trade crypto currency at https://www.cointouch.com/

No fees or ID verification. Very easy to get started.