# How do I buy bitcoins using a prepaid credit card? [Canada]

Tags: exchanges, debitcard, canada

I live in Canada, I don't have a credit card. I want to buy a prepaid one and but some bitcoins. How can I do this? Or is there a way to use my debit card? Or even go to my bank and do it.

Comment: Related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am Canadian and I have used both these services:

[www.cavirtex.com](http://www.cavirtex.com)

They can be added as Online Bill Payee at RBC, BMO, Scotia, or TD Bank (takes 1 to 2 days)

and/or

[www.canadianbitcoins.com](http://www.canadianbitcoins.com)

I never left my seat and Bitcoins were deposited with the hour!

They use TD Canada Trust, and you can add them as a Payee by calling your EasyLine banking, then make an Instant payment to them.

Comment: Hello Joel and welcome to the StackExchange. You can post relevant links in the answer without having to write "www dot". However, please refrain from self-promotion that is not relevant to the question. This is frowned upon in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Using a prepaid card is the hard way.

Your better option is to use an exchange.

Does your bank have online Bill Payment?  If so, you might be able to send funds to [CA VirtEx](http://cavirtex.com/) using that method.

You can instead deposit cash at Royal Bank, Bank of Montreal or ScotiaBank, and it will be credited to your account at CA VirtEx.

Another Canadian exchange, [Canadian Bitcoins](http://www.canadianbitcoins.com/), accepts cash via XpressPost, (or in-person at their office in Ottowa).

There might be other methods that work for you as well:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

There's quite a variety of methods:

Comment: I believe that as of April 2013 CAVirtEx no longer accepts payments via cash deposits at banks. See https://www.cavirtex.com/news