# Is there a way to buy or sell Bitcoins for Iceland Kronas?

Tags: exchanges, currencies, money, europe

Say I was living in Iceland and wanted to convert my local currency to Bitcoin and back. What are my options?

Comment: Iceland is in the SEPA region, so perhaps they can make SEPA transfers?

Comment: @StephenGornick Yeah, probably, but the costs would be higher than local transfers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 3):

Trade with others who might be local:

- http://www.LocalBitcoins.com

Forum users might check in on a thread like this:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=109453.0