# What's the safest way to buy bitcoins in India?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, market, india

I have came across multiple companies selling BTC, but I’m not sure which one to trust. How can I find a safe way to buy bitcoins in India?

Comment: related: [How can I convert bitcoins to Indian rupees and vice-versa?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5892/5406)

Answer (score 3):

There are several legit companies where you can buy and sell Bitcoin officially in India such as Zebpay, Unocoin, Coinsecure,and Btcxindia.

I have personally used Unocoin and Zebpay, both are good.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice, any idea which one is the cheapest aka which takes the least transaction fee?

Comment: also, does any of them happen to use easy mode of transactions like debit card or credit card?

Comment: go for zebpay if u are a new user and want to purchase without much technical knowledge, its a mobile wallet which is linked with your mobile number for security purpose...you can use ur bank account to make payment to zebpay acc and they will provide you the equivalent bits. if u want to use debit/credit card go for unocoin

Answer (score 1):

Btcxindia is good. For peer to peer trading you can use localbitcoins