# Ways to buy bitcoin (I'm in the US)

Tags: buy-bitcoins, bitcoin-credit-card, debitcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

I just want a straightforward answer, I read a few answers but the explanations are convoluted. Where can I buy bitcoins online? Is there a site or sites? Do/can we buy them with a bank card or credit card or directly with my bank account? If not, how the hell am I supposed to get them lol

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites indeed and some over the counter transaction, but for the sake of being short.

Try: [Mt. Gox](https://mtgox.com/)

You can draw money from your bank account and put it in escrow for BTC and vice-versa... It's known as the biggest bitcoin exchange over the world.