# Can I buy bitcoins with moneygram in Australia?

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins

I notice you can do it like this in the U.S http://vimeo.com/44849463 but is the same method possible in Australia? We do have moneygram at 7-11's here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one of the bank exchanges such as [omnicoins](https://www.omnicoins.com) or [bitXoin](https://www.bitXoin.com/) for this function. There are less fees as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a easy and safe way to [buy bitcoins with MoneyGram](http://www.coinmama.com/buy-bitcoins-with-moneygram/) you can check out CoinMama's exchange service, they work with both MoneyGram and Western Union and can deliver the bitcoins within a few hours.

Comment: Are you affiliated with coinmama? I noticed that you also posted a link to the site on [this question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/11826/3930).