# How can I buy Bitcoins in the UK now that Blockchain.info has suspended its deposits?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, europe, uk

After blockchain.info suspended Pingit, there is no convenient way to buy a small quantity of bitcoins. Any other alternatives to acquire bitcoins (mining or working are out of the questions.)

I've heard a [SEPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Euro_Payments_Area) transfer will allow UK bank accounts holders to utilize European exchanges, unfortunately I am concerned about the legality of these exchanges (ie: who owns/runs the exchange, for example.) As such I would like the company to be based in the UK, where I have more protection if the transaction goes awry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Comment: doesn't mt gox allow bank transfers or cc payments?

Answer (score 8):

For small BTC purchases in the UK, https://localbitcoins.com/ (LocalBitcoins) is the only viable option right now that I know of.

There are other methods, mostly involving bank transfer arrangements, but be very careful to figure out how much you end up paying in total fees for it. It doesn't make much of a difference with large BTC orders, but for small amounts it's a fair % of costs.

Comment: SEPA purchases are callbackable up to 10 days, so if you trade over SEPA transfers make use you pick LocalBitcoins.com user with high reputation http://localbitcoins.blogspot.fi/2013/06/localbitcoinscom-bank-account-frozen.html

Answer (score 4):

QuickBitcoin (http://quickbitcoin.co.uk) accepts UK bank transfers for bitcoins.  There are no fees, and transactions are very quick.

Comment: that looks well dubious and a rip off

Comment: No fees but the exchange rate is pretty bad (approximately 5% higher than current market price at the time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using [BitBargain.co.uk](http://bitbargain.co.uk) - it is a cut above the Mt Gox price, but not as much so as QuickBitcoin. You'll likely get a better deal if you can find someone on LocalBitcoins though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the Bitcoin comparison tool found at: http://cheapbitcoins.co.uk - you can get the best prices for in GBP, because most bitcoin exchanges are not based in the UK.