# Where can I trade BTC/USD with a small transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, buy-bitcoins

I don't need a leveraged account. I just want to trade with real money.

The Mt. Gox transaction fee is 0.60%. Is there a place with a lower transaction fee?

Comment: related: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406)

Answer (score 3):

Base fees:

- [Mt. Gox](https://mtgox.com/): 0.6%
- [Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/fee_schedule/): 0.5%
- [Intersango](https://intersango.com/): 0.65%
- [Bitcoin-Central](https://bitcoin-central.net/s/fees): 0.498%

Comment: Can you update on the non-base fees?

Comment: @Pacerier feel free to edit my post

Answer (score 0):

btc-e is a good choice for low fees.

https://btc-e.com/

Currently fees are set at 0.2%, The best available at the moment, although getting money in and out is quite tricky.

Comment: Can cost as low as you want, but if you can't withdraw...

Answer (score 0):

You can buy bitcoins through Ripple:  https://ripple.com

Comment: Although the markets there for anything other than XRP currently aren't very deep and the spreads are wide. Hopefully this will improve in the future.