# How to integrate a Bitcoin wallet service in my website

Tags: wallet

I'm a new web programmer and I'm building a website if a Member sign-up he get a wallet, and I want to make this website like a bank .... so when he registers a wallet he can send bitcoin to the wallet and the Website tells him how much he have of bitcoin just like a bank I'm not creating a bank but the idea have the same concept

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: you have skype ? I have knowledge about that. and guide u step by step.

Comment: So, do you want to create a web wallet service or what exactly?

Comment: yes i want to create a website "electronic currencies Trader" and the problem is that i need to make a wellat to every user.

Comment: possible duplicate: [What would it take to create my own Bitcoin exchange?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18540/5406)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if you really want to do this you utilise the blockchain.info API and their wallet service. This isn't a project for a novice programmer, if anybody actually trusted your site enough to send funds to it the chances are your site would be hacked repeatedly. You need to be a serious security expert and experienced programmer to store user's Bitcoin.

Start with something safer :)