# Can I still transfer USD from MtGox to Dwolla?

Tags: mtgox, dwolla, money-transfer

Can I still transfer USD from MtGox to Dwolla, and then Dwolla to my bank account? I've done this several times in the past, before the DHS seizure of MtGox's Dwolla funds. It's hard to get an anwser from MtGox.
I've got about 5-10 Bitcoins I'd like to convert to USD.

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question is MtGox --> Dwolla. The linked question above is Dwolla --> MtGox.

Comment: `Dwolla is now unable to move money to and from Mutum Sigillum` <-- from the Dwolla announcement

Comment: What are some other ways to convert Bitcoin to USD in the US?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins

Comment: @NickODell : Read more carefully: It said BTC to $, NOT $ to BTC.

Comment: @MichaelHardy All of the answers on that question (well, not mining) work in both directions.