# What is the best way to purchase Bitcoins quickly?

Tags: transactions, wallet, exchanges

What is the best way to purchase Bitcoins quickly? I don't want to wait a month.

Comment: Depends on your location...........

Answer (score 7):

On [LocalBitcoins.com](http://localbitcoins.com) you can get bitcoins bought under one hour. Just pick a trader who has good reputation (not a scammer) and low response times.

Answer (score 4):

There's lots of information available here: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

[coinbase.com](http://coinbase.com) has a pretty good reputation I understand, and I find the interface to be quite cleverly designed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out bitinstant.com

You can deposit cash and get btc sent to your email or btc address right after you pay.

Answer (score 2):

It really is all about your location. In some countries, it's harder to get set up to sell bitcoins than other countries.

If you're in the UK, try one of these to get near-instant Bitcoins:

- [Bittylicious](http://www.bittylicious.com/)
- [BitBargain](http://www.bitbargain.com)
- Local Bitcoins (UK)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Coinbase. That's how I got my first 10 coins.

When I wanted to get my first coins I was already registered on Gox but wasn't sure how long international transfers would take.

I signed up with them and did the bank deposit verification method. I believe I verified the next day and bought 10 coins. I got the coins immediately but for anti-fraud measures I couldn't spend them for a few days (looks like on 8/20 the wait is 4 business days)

After being more trusted the buy limit goes up and your coins are available immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you live in the Netherlands, you can use [bitonic.nl](http://bitonic.nl) to purchase Bitcoins via iDEAL. You get them in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the UK then check out https://bit121.co.uk as they are a legitimate exchange with UK based banking. Most bank transfers within the UK are usually instant and you don't have to pay the higher fees when dealing with foreign banks.

Answer (score -1):

Probably Ebay....From a trusted seller   via bank transfer

Answer (score -2):

Bitcoin is definitely in its infancy.  I have bank accounts all over the world in USD, GBP, and CHF.  I have accounts on Coinbase, BTC-e, CampBX, Mt. Gox, Bitstamp, LocalBitcoins, and others.

Yet, it is next to impossible to move fiat currency to these exchanges.  In fact, I have only ever been able to buy bitcoins on Localbitcoins, thanks to the immediate transfer facility in the U.K. banking system.

For people who want to buy in USD, which is where the major exchange volumes are, there has not been a way to transfer USD to an exchange without a currency exchange, bank and exchange fees, and a long wait.

CampBX is adding ACH transfer on November 20.

Coinbase not only requires all bank and credit cards to be based in the U.S., they also require the holder to be based in the U.S.  This essentially restricts Coinbase to the 4% of the world that lives in the U.S.

It is frustrating watching the volatile price action and being unable to trade because I can't get fiat to the exchanges.

Comment: you describe the problem, why the question is interesting istead of answering the question.

Comment: The answer depends on where one lives, what you regard as an acceptable transaction cost, what currency you want to buy in, as well as other variables.   Given the unclear question, my comment is as close to an answer as you can get.

Comment: So, you are saying, the question couldn't be answered that's why you wrote something other than an answer? ;)

Comment: You have a point.  I would have (and should have) commented and asked the poster to define the question in a way that one could frame an answer.  However, again, I do not have sufficient points to do this, so I gave some general feedback that might be of interest.

Comment: I think you can always flag posts, here if you come to the conclusion that the question is bad you may use "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad". In this case "off-topic" would also be appropriate.

Comment: With 17 points, I can't do anything.

Comment: I am sorry, not everyone, but with 15 points you can flag. ;)