# Buy bitcoins with my vef (bolivares) in Venezuela without wire transfer

Tags: trading

I want to buy bitcoins with my vef (bolivares) from my account in Venezuela.
How can I go about it?, we don't have a way of sending a wire transfer overseas in our currency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Comment: @Murch yes and no. Venezuela posses especial problems to its citizens, since by law they have an annual hard limit of how much they can spend in foreign currency when traveling abroad or in online purchases, plus the gap between the official exchange rate and the one in the gray and black markets is way too high. All that leaves face-to-face purchases, selling goods/services and mining as practically the only options.

Comment: Have a look at [FoxBit](http://foxbit.exchange) it seems that they can help you!

Comment: Maybe https://purse.io/

Answer (score 3):

There are no Bitcoin exchanges in Venezuela, and no exchanges that support BTC/VEF.

You might find a trade by putting an offer in on LocalBitcoins, or there might be an offer to sell by someone [located near you](https://localbitcoins.com/location/VE/Caracas/).

You said you can't do an international wire transfer. A bank wire (in USD, EUR, etc.) to an exhange such as Mt. Gox, BITSTAMP, etc., is not an option for you then apparently.

If you can trade with someone in another country in your region (e.g., Colombia, Peru, Brazil, etc.) there are exchanges in those countries.

Without the use of exchanges, another method of obtaining bitcoins is to offer goods and services with payment in bitcons.  [Turismo Surpremo](http://www.turismosupremo.com) is a business that does this.  You might even be able to buy their excess coins perhaps.

It's possible that working with [BitPagos](https://www.bitpagos.net), a payment processor that specifically targets Latin America, might yield a method to acquire coins.

Answer (score 0):

LocalBitcoins is pretty much the only why you can buy bitcoins in VEF.
 and it would help you a lot if you have a bank account in banesco or bancomercantil
 since most of the transactions happens in does banks.

Answer (score 0):

Airtm.io the best way to buy bitcoin in Venezuela with Bolivars, a based on Uphold.com and super safe.

https://medium.com/@airtm.io/bitcoin-brokers-and-exchanges-grow-their-business-with-airtm-749df3f20424#.ae7lzub4p

https://medium.com/@airtm.io/corredores-y-casas-de-cambio-bitcoin-crecen-su-negocio-con-airtm-46442f456eee#.j3h2swzds