# mobile sites/apps and other things

Tags: mobile

I honestly have only heard about this because of the tv show, the good wife.  I didn't know it was real. I am very curious as to what bitcoin is, can do and also, if there are mobile friendly apps and sites for the use of bitcoins. Also, explaining this mining thing a little better, would help. I am not sure how that earns me bitcoins or if I have to pay in with paper money to get bitcoins or if it is even legal to have bitcoins. (seeing that you have a siteshutdown is concerning to me with the fbi doing it). Anyway....thanks for taking the time to read this....I look forward to the answers.  Also....one last thing.....can I buy things like computers, software, cameras, editing software with bitcoins if I save enough of them?

Comment: Hi jason, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Please have a look at the [about] to get a better understanding of how this site works: We are trying to build a good resource of questions and answers, which means that one is supposed to focus on one question per "question". Also, it is appreciated when the question shows previous research effort. Most of the questions you have asked have answers on this or other websites, for example have looks at [tag:mining], [tag:mobile], [How do you obtain Bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins).

Answer (score 1):

That's lot of questions!!

The first thing I recommend is to browse the pages here: http://bitcoin.org/en/

As a bitcoin user/spender you don't need to think much of how mining works, just that they are crucial to keeping the entire system safe.

Other than mining you can get bitcoins from an exchange, or other services. https://localbitcoins.com/ is a site where you can find real people that sell bitcoins and you can agree to met someone face-to-face. An exchange can be thought of brokerage account, you can buy bitcoins for a commission the same way you would buy company stock.

There are a lot of different things you can spend bitcoins on, must of it are online. For real shops that accept bitcoin this site http://coinmap.org/ will guide you

Obviously there is a lot more to be said but I recommend you to start reading. This forum is more for technical questions on the bitcoin network I think but there are other forums for miners, users, investors etc.