# Worth investing in to a cloud mining companies?

Tags: mining-profitability, cloud-mining

Worth investing in to companies like hashflare.io or genesis-mining.com?

Hashflare:

During black friday there's discount - 1TH/s for 100$. Maintenance fee for 1 TH/s is 0.4$ == 0.0005 BTC.

1 TH/s gives 85-90000 satoshi - 50000 satoshi MEF = 35000 satoshi profit (0.257809$) * 30 = 7.71$ per month, 7.71*13 ~ 100$. So, ROI is 13 months...

But profit for 1 TH/s would vary during a year. So 90000 satoshi per 1 TH/s might be even lower, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, profit will be even lower. Hash rate has grown from 540 PH/s to 1800 PH/s in the last year. At that rate it will take much longer than 13 months for your ROI.

Comment: if hashrate goes down for some reason, then payouts would be higher again? Can we predict total hashrate for the next year?

Comment: Yes, but why should that happen? And no, we cannot. You also have to consider the price development of Bitcoin. In the past years it was always a better deal to just directly buy bitcoins unless you ran your own large mining operation with access to very cheap power.

Comment: so with my own ASIC's i would get better results?

Comment: It depends. What is your power price, how large will your operation be? If your hardware breaks you're clearly worse off if it's your own instead of theirs… I've written more here: [When is it a good time to invest in Cloud mining?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41088/5406), also see the other linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud mining can be profitable and ever well-profitable (some contracts have over 200% profit predictions) but you need to choose company and contracts wisely!

There is lot of scam on this market and ever trustworthy companies can have non-profitable contracts (like it happened with Dash contracts after ASICs for Dash mining were invented).

I have written detailed analytic article about cloud mining - [Cloud Mining - FAQ, Profits & Risks](https://medium.com/@mic_mart/cloud-mining-faq-profits-risks-8f60d5a9e94f) .

It's big, detailed and explains most common questions, compare companies on the market and contracts available.
There is also interesting profit calculations there which will help to choose wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, Cloud mining can be profitable and ever well-profitable but you need to choose company and contracts wisely and watch out for the risk involved well in advance.