Should this be legal to charge a person a hashrate that is meant for 8 decimal point system then take and apply it to a 14 decimal system in bitcoin
I've been minning with Bitcoin crypto cloud mining company for a couple of months now.So everyday I go in and check on everything just to make sure the miners are still going, I'm mining at a hashrate of 1.53ths and that rate costs around $90 a month but I'm now into 3 months of mining with this particular mining company and this is the number I've got to show for all of my hard work and devotion to the bitcoin cause...(0.00006034789567mbtc)that's 60million three hundred and forty seven thousand eight hundred and ninetyfive and sixtyseven hashes in the last three months. But how much is it worth. Because I'm looking at it and I'm afraid that's it's only worth around $4.34 when I've already spent nearly $300.00. But here in 5 days I'm coming up another decimal point. And that makes a big difference. I want to withdraw the bits I have and put them somewhere that they can earn 20% extra to 50% extra in rewards instead of letting them just sit. Where thit is. What I'm afraid of is. If I do that,.will I lose that gain I get with the next decimal point.

If by "cloud mining" you mean you don't have your own physical mining hardware, you are being scammed. If they had profitable hardware, they'd just use it themselves, not let you rent it.

You ask "Should this be legal" - but all fraud of this sort is illegal. I suggest you stop giving money to criminals - doing so doesn't help the Bitcoin cause, it harms it.

Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41084/5406
