# Are there any legitimate cloud mining services?

Tags: cloud-mining

Are there any cloud-mining services that you can earn Bitcoin with and aren't Ponzi schemes?

Comment: related: [How do cloud hashing companies profit? (leasing hashing power)](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/34219/5406), [When is it a good time to invest in Cloud mining?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41084/5406), also see: [BCT: Cloudmining 101 (ponzi risk assessment)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=878387.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the cloud mining services are scam and doesn't stays in the long run. You can check out this thread to avoid cloud mining: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=878387.0

Good luck.