# Can i still use the old address to recieve Bitcoin with Bitcoin.com Wallet

Tags: wallet, address, cloud-mining

I tried Cloud Minning recently And I use Bitcoin.com Wallet to register bitcoinonlinepool.com, today I accidentally press the change address button, will my account still able to recieve Bitcoin?

Btw, is bitcoinonlinepool.com a legit or spam

Answer (score 2):

> **I tried Cloud Minning recently**

Cloud mining services are scams generally

- [Are there any legitimate cloud mining services?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41367/13866)
- [Is a cloud mining subscription worth it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/52166/13866)
- [Cloud mining questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=cloud+mining)

---

> **I accidentally press the change address button, will my account still able to receive Bitcoin?**

Yes. Addresses can receive multiple payments. Addresses never expire.

- [Address reuse questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=address+reuse)

Address re-use is only a *privacy* concern and probably only a concern if you have several *different* people sending money to the same address or if you then pay *multiple* parties with funds previously received at one address.

You mention the Bitcoin.com wallet - I'm not familiar with it. If it is a [custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) then you'd need to contact Bitcoin.com support to ask if they have any problems associating your account with re-used addresses they have generated for you. This is because sometimes services call an account a wallet when it isn't a normal Bitcoin wallet and its up to each such business how they choose to associate addresses with customers' accounts. I'd be surprised if it was a problem but you'd have to ask to be certain. Remember that **Bitcoin.com is to Bitcoin as [Dollar.com](https://dollar.com) is to the US Dollar** - the businesses are unrelated to the currency except as users of it.

---

> **is bitcoinonlinepool.com a legit or spam**

- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866)