# Want to buy bitcoin from Bangladesh

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

I'm from Bangladesh. I would like to buy bitcoins. So I went to Buybitcoin.com  and filled an order. Later I googled that site and read a lot about if being a scam site. So I'm a bit scared now. do not want to be scammed.

I've already tried ecurrencyzone.com but they do not take bank deposits from Bangladesh. this is terrible. Anyway can any of you fellow Indians guide me to proper genuine links where I can buy Bitcoins. My options are Western Union, Moneygram and best option is Bank deposit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way for you would be somthing like [localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/country/BD). But you can use any exchange where you can transfer money to from your bank (Bitstamp, Justcoin, Bitcurex, ...)

Comment: I user localbitcoins too and would also recommend it, having similar problems in the UK. It removes the middle-man-bank to an extent.

Comment: This does not answer the question as localbitcoins do not facilitate bitcoin buying in Bangladesh. The main problem seems to be that you cannot transfer money away from Bangladesh normally.