# I live in viet nam and I want to buy bitcoin. How would I do that?

Tags: transactions

I would like to buy bitcoins in viet nam. How would I do that?

Comment: @gary welcome to the site. This question has been asked a number of times for several countries in this site. You can try the search box in the upper-right corner - as others indicated, most probably "local bitcoins" will be for you.

Comment: Hello gary, this question has a generic answer at [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins).

Answer (score 1):

I would say try https://localbitcoins.com
You can buy from other people in your area/country.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to contact someone on https://localbitcoins.com/country/VN

Its listed there. There are few users with reputation offering bitcoins for western union