# Beginning the process of buying bitcoins

Tags: buy-bitcoins, privacy, coldstorage

I am interested in the process of buying bitcoins, but I have many questions. First and foremost, how do I begin this process? I am looking to make my bitcoin wallet as secure as possible, so how would I go about doing that? How would I incorporate the process of buying bitcoins with Tor?

Comment: Hey moltar, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Thank you for your contribution. Our question and answer platform performs best, if you only ask one question per post, but yours looks more like at least two, perhaps three distinct questions. It would be best, if you edited your post to narrow it down to one issue, and then ask the others as separate questions. You might want to have a look at [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/5406) and [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406), as your questions have some answers already.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your wallet to be as safe as possible, you'll have to store it *cold*, i.e. create a [Paper Wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet). There a several options with different safety levels:

- Use an online generator, like [Bitaddress](http://www.bitaddress.org) and print the generated address/key
- Use an offline computer with a ubuntu-live cd to generate address/key and print it

You can send bitcoins to this wallet, even though it's created offline, and never has seen the internet, or vice versa. For further reading about this, I recommend the first link, as there are some recommendations you should read first.

Buying bitcoins with Tor is a little more complicated. I never did it, and couldn't find anything about it. [PrivateInternetAcces](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-buy-bitcoins-anonymously-in-the-us-instantly/) said [Bitinstant](http://www.bitinstant.com/) was a good option, but the article is 2 years old, and bitinstant returns a white page. A local trade is a good option, find some people on [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/)