# Is guadagnarebitcoins a scam?

Tags: earnings

I found this site:

http://guadagnarebitcoins.altervista.org

What do you think? Is it a scam? Are the things listed on it scams?

Comment: related: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406). By the way, "earn" and "free" are contradictory. Which of the two are you interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site covers two topics:

1. A basic introduction to Bitcoin
2. How one might be able to obtain Bitcoin for "free"

I'll discuss only item 2.  Several possibilities for earning Bitcoin are presented:

1. Mining
2. Performing sponsored actions
3. Using certain services that offer Bitcoin as an incentive
4. Performing [mechanical turk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk) tasks
5. Investing
6. Betting

The page at **guadagnarebitcoins.altervista.org** does not itself offer any service, and appears to simply offer information.  Therefore, the site itself is not a "scam."

However, as the site references a number of different third-party sites and services, you may find that your experience with those individual sites  will vary along a continuum of legitimacy (or lack thereof).

All of the proposed methods involve some non-zero amount of effort.

Considering the proposed methods ideally involves a good deal of judgment, self-knowledge, and reflection with questions like:

- Will mining result in the profit I think it will?
- Is this a good [ROI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) for my time and money?
- How much do I know about investing?
- How much time and/or money can I afford to lose?
- Is gambling a good way to earn money for me?
- Do I have reasonable confidence that the service will pay me?

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Bitcoin is money *(or at least treated as such)*. It is just another currency, just like USD, EUR, YEN, etc.

So what you are asking: How do I earn money without working:

- Arbitrage
- Interest
- Slavery
- Gambling *(however, I discourage anyone to do so, better open a casino)*
- *there might be more*

All of these ways might need assets of some sort, and some time invested. *Wait, time invested? Isn't that work?* - Yes

If you are not already filthy rich, you won't make bitcoin/usd/moneys without putting in time (a.k.a work).

If you do not have enough money to invest, get a job and make more money. Invest this. Only invest money that you can afford to lose.