# How To Buy Bitcoins Within Wallet?

Tags: wallet, armory

I recently downloaded the Armory Wallet for my Mac. It appears to work great, but is there any way I can purchase Bitcoins via an exchange on the wallet interface itself? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

No, in general wallets are just tools to manage bitcoins already in your possession. The only exception I can think of is Mycelium, which includes a functionality to find buyers and sellers nearby.

To find out how to get bitcoins, check out [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406).

Comment: So basically I would have to create another wallet on the exchange and then send them to the wallet on my computer?

Comment: @PhilipAdams Yes. Some exchanges will payout directly to an address but most you do your trade and then withdraw.