# Where can I buy bitcoin with wire?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want bitcoin to be sent to my address after I wire the money.

How can I do so?

I want something with less kurs fee. So little comission

Comment: likely duplicate of [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406)

Comment: the answers there do not explain which method accept wire transfer.

Comment: Exchanges accept wire transfers.