# How to purchase and send bitcoins

Tags: transactions, wallet

I tried Blockchain in 2015 through an account with Laissez Faire, but could not get help signing up, so I just let the account go. Now I decided to try it again and I am still lost.  How can one send bitcoins to others if you haven't purchased any? Please, I cannot learn without asking questions whether the questions sound dumb or not.  Please help educate me.

Comment: I am not sure what your question really is?  I only see one question mark in your post and the answer is you cannot send bitcoins until you have some, which most people do by purchasing.

Comment: In addition to asking, you can also learn by reading what's already been asked.  Perhaps http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no credit in Bitcoin. Therefore, you cannot send any bitcoins until you have either purchased or earned some.

Comment: How do you purchase bitcoins?

Comment: @Precious: As Nate already linked above: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406)