# How to earn my first bitcoin in baby steps?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I don't know any thing about bit coin , what I know that it digital currency maintained by people and not banks.

How do I start earning my bitcoins ? OK After earning this bitcoins ? What all things I can buy in real world or it just to pay for only services to service provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HOW TO BUY BITCOINS**

1) From exchanges. Exchanges are many based on countries. [UNOCOIN](https://www.unocoin.com) is a popular one for India. Alternatively, if your nationality is different from what I presumed, you can have a look at this site for many exchanges and wallets: [COINDESK](http://www.coindesk.com/information/how-can-i-buy-bitcoins/). You can create a bitcoin wallet here: [BLOCKCHAIN](https://blockchain.info/)

2) Have a look at this link for more detailed explanation: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)

**WHERE CAN I SPEND THEM**

You can spend them on websites/services which ACCEPT bitcoins as a mode of payment just like Paypal, Credit Card or Debit Card.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to the buying process provided by @trollster -

If you would like to *earn* bitcoin (rather than paying for them directly) there are a few ways to do so.  Mining is one example, but it requires purchasing specialized equipment and will likely entail a good deal of research as well.  You might choose to sell goods or services in exchange for bitcoin.

**A more simple and practical way to earn small amounts of bitcoin is by completing tasks or surveys online.**  There is an array of websites that offer this form of compensation - which will vary in terms of compensation level, accessibility, reputation, and reliability.  From my own experience, I can attest to the fact that www.BitcoinGet.com *did* pay out (which was my biggest concern).  Earning a full bitcoin through this medium alone would take quite a bit of time - but is the only option I can recommend that requires zero capital.

If you do want to earn some bitcoin in that manner, you should still create a bitcoin wallet and an address by following step 1 from @trollster

Welcome to Bitcoin!

Comment: can I earn from the blog, if I have good traffic on site. https://androidapksget.blogspot.com/