# How do I buy the bitcoins?

Tags: transactions

I do not know how to buy the bitcoins.
Could someone tell me how I get rich with the bitcoins?
Why are the question standards so high?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for investment advice.

Comment: "Why are the question standards so high?" http://lesswrong.com/lw/c1/wellkept_gardens_die_by_pacifism/

Comment: please close, i tried to delete... was kinda a joke but not as funny in execution, especially when someone tried to help me.  sry, wont do again, cheers!

Comment: I read that article.  feel more ashamed

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated: We are making an effort to keep quality standards high on this site in order to make it useful and attractive for experts to contribute. Regarding your question of how to buy bitcoins, please see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406. Satire is hard to recognize, when it fits well within the ~20 or so posts that we delete daily because they are very similar. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering to the main question ''how do I buy bitcoins'' I would tell you that bitcoins are not the only cryptocurrency available on the market.
Since when bitcoins were born, many other cryptocurrencies were founded.
So, to answer to your question ''Could someone tell me how I get rich with the bitcoins?'': you probably wouldn't get rich by buying bitcoins, since bitcoins became very popular and the main peak has already took place.
In order to ''get rich'' (if you are totally unaware of the risks of buying cryptocurrencies I would suggest you to not buy anything) you should buy a cryptocurrency which is less rated than bitcoins, hoping that it will increase.
For example if you buy ripple (XRP- which is actually around 1 $ worth) and it gets to 100 $, you earn 100 x you first investment.
But there's not a rule to get rich by trading with cryptocurrencies and before take any action you should first be informed of the risks and possibilities of such cryptocurrencies.

Comment: _"main peak has already took place"_

why do you think so? any proofs?

Comment: Well, there's not a proof. This observation is only based on the likelihood of the event (which is absolutely estimated and cannot be demonstrated). When bitcoin was born it was worth 2 cents of euro, now it's more or less around 15.000 euro (depending on the day). This means that bitcoin increased of 750.000 times. Of course I cannot demonstrate that bitcoin will not increase again and will become worth 11.250.000.000 of euro, but that's not very likely to be. Of course it doesn't exist a proof for that, this observation is only based on common sense.