# How to add money

Tags: payment

I'm trying to send money to an address but it keeps coming with error message.

Do I need to have money in my bitcoin wallet first before sending to someone and how do i add money please?

Comment: Hi, which wallet are you using? Where are you trying to send bitcoin? What is the error message? If you're not more specific, I'm afraid no one will be able to answer your questions.
And obviously you need to have some bitcoin to be able to send it to another address.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin is like cash, you can only spend it if you have some already. Since the Bitcoin network doesn't transfer dollars or other government currencies, but sends bitcoins, you cannot just link up a card or bank account to start sending money. You first have to purchase bitcoins.

There are some wallets that offer an integrated service for purchasing bitcoins which you could use to both buy and then send, but this tends to come with a price of course. To learn more about getting bitcoins, you could check out for example: [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406)