# Where can I buy bitcoin directly in to my wallet

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I would like to buy Bitcoin directly into my muun wallet.

Possible options that I'm aware of

- Buying directly from someone
- Using a bitcoin atm Buying from
- Coinmamma

What I tried
Bisq (Would not install on mac) and I understand that you get a wallet with them meaning you would pay miners to transact into my Bisq wallet and then I would have to pay again to transfer into my muun bitcoin wallet.

Are there any other options and what are the fees?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started)

Comment: While  it does provide a starting point for me to go check out a lot of options with this link https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_exchanges
It doesn't directly mention if any of these sites have their own wallet or if I can transfer directly into my wallet. 

I think having a comprehensive list of all the sites where to get coins directly into your wallet can be a huge financial saver especially since I plan to shop groceries on a regular basis with bitcoin. If no one replies with the answer then I would probably be able to answer msyslf in about a week.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406)

Comment: no my question is to buy bitcoin directly into my wallet, not through some exchange that has their own wallet.